Should we repeat tags in question title?
For context, I created post at SE question on SE Meta by mistake, while it was intended to come here.  As @Elements In Space suggested, I repost it here

The answer below (and in the duplicate) are good, but I really think you should ask about this on Music Meta. I believe Music.SE is somewhat of an exception because most questions there aren’t related to programming, and so most users aren’t expecting to need to look for language tags. – Elements In Space


In a comment to this question:
LilyPond - Put ALL noteheads to the left of stems, regardless of stem direction
a user asked OP to repeat the tag [lilypond] in the question title. This doesn't seem to follow the pattern of many other questions I see on SE. Is it really something we want the people who ask questions to do?

@DWW256 While adding proper tags is correct, also mentioning the software in the title (you don't need square brackets, just put it in the context of the phrase) or, at least, the question body is always better. […]


My original post was closed as a duplicate of Should questions include "tags" in their titles? which actually satisfies me. However, MTP SE is a specific context combining a wide variety of fields, artistic and technical. I admit I often can't make any sense out of a question, until I read the tags. Still, does it justify repeating the tags in the question title?

As I replied in a comment, I agree that repeating the tag everywhere is redundant and should be avoided.
And, after some thinking, I realized that a lot of questions on StackOverflow follow the common rule, I just don't think too much about it because I normally follow specific tag filters, but even I sometimes removed tags in titles.
There's a difference, though: even when ignoring tags, the "main tag" reference (the programming language) is almost always clear from the context, because most posts contain some code snippets that make the language identifiable. Also, the differences in languages make questions more "compartmentalized", and most people will just follow tags for languages they are interested into, which is probably the opposite of what a common user of music.se users does.
Now, in my opinion, the point is not if tags should or shouldn't be repeated, but how they are considered.
In my understanding, the purpose of tags doesn't include to be a required aspect to understand a question: the post should be clear even if there was no tag, it shouldn't be the only and final piece of the puzzle that allows its comprehension, which is what raised my suggestion to the OP: tags are not highlighted in the visual context of the post (title and body), and they are also not always consistent (it may be rare on music.se, but it's quite common on SO, with people using wrong or irrelevant tags), but we shouldn't have to read a full question only to find out at its bottom that, for example, we're not interested in it, or we cannot answer, because we finally realize what the OP is talking about.
So, this may be a non-problem: the point is to write clear questions. If the post is clear, repeating the tags in the title is obviously redundant and, therefore, wrong.
But if a tag is the only aspect that allows the post to finally make sense, it's also wrong to completely avoid it, even in the question body.
